# Does the Nikon EH-5a AC Adapter also charge the battery

Tags: nikon, dslr, adapter, charger

On "older" Nikons like the D50, D90... that have the DC IN port, when an EH-5a AC Adapter is connected, does it JUST power the camera, or does it also charge the battery?  I haven't been able to find a good, solid answer online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Nikon USA, it is just a power supply and does not charge the battery.

> Q: Will this also charge the camera batteries or is it just a power
>   supply?
>
> A: It's just a power supply.

See Q&A at the bottom of this page.

http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product-Archive/Power-Adapters/EH-5a-AC-Adapter.html